# Upload audio as instant link with download button in telethon bot

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to send mp3 file to the user from telethon bot, when I do that with `bot.send_file(supports_streaming=True)` it arrives with delay like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/69oau.png

I also tried `bot.upload_file` which should upload file on telegram server and return `InputFile`, but calling `bot.send_file(file=input_file)` gives the same result.

What I want is to provide instant link to file with download button like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/epRQs.png

I've seen this in one audio book bot, it gives this download button immediately even for 200MB files. Help me to implement this please.

Answer (score 0):

[Telethon's docs for `send_file`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file) says you can pass `supports_streaming=True`.

Comment: It gives me result as in the first picture.

Comment: Ah, sneaky edit  You can't send a file that hasn't finished uploading, as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like telethon doesn't have functionality for this kind of problem yet, but I found super easy solution in aiogram library, it accepts links as well as files which was useful in my case.
https://aiogram.2038.io/api/methods/send_audio/